# Parsing by Value / Reference

Tags: code

My teacher is on the subject of parsing, as I type this. He has defined it as literally passing a value, claiming that they're interchangeable and mean the same thing.

He is being FRUSTRATINGLY ambiguous. What is the act of parsing? Is it just setting a value generally? is it only to do with Arguments / parameters. Is it the input of values? I know parsing by reference is when you reference something for example inputting the variable "A" set to the value "1", where as Value is directly inputting a value such as "1" or a string "Hello".

The only language I can (barely) write is Python.

Comment: There is no such thing as "parsing by value" or "parsing by reference".

Comment: Maybe you meant "passing by value" / "passing by reference" http://courses.washington.edu/css342/zander/css332/passby.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't be frustrated.
It's "Passing by reference" Vs. "Passing by value".
I just saw one of the best explanations at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value):

Say I want to share a web page with you.

If I tell you the URL, I'm passing by reference. You can use that URL to see the same web page I can see. If that page is changed, we both see the changes. If you delete the URL, all you're doing is destroying your reference to that page - you're not deleting the actual page itself.

If I print out the page and give you the printout, I'm passing by value. Your page is a disconnected copy of the original. You won't see any subsequent changes, and any changes that you make (e.g. scribbling on your printout) will not show up on the original page. If you destroy the printout, you have actually destroyed your copy of the object - but the original web page remains intact.